# CKEditor on ASP.NET MVC - how to edit a document

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I have found a lot of tutorials on how to setup CKEditor on ASP.NET MVC, but they were mostly focused on how to create documents. I need not only to create, but to edit documents as well.

I use a basic razor action to create a textarea,

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description)
```

and basic javascript to setup the editor.

```
CKEDITOR.replace('Description', {
        language: 'cs'
    });
```

However, my editor loads blank. Always, even if model.Description contains already some  text. Add the setData function only made the Rich text editor disappear and loaded the textarea with HTML (escaped, as I checked in the source). My questions are:

1. How can I set the text to edit in the editor?
2. Isn't there a more effective way or e better editor to handle this?

Comment: do you see any errors in JavaScript console? And you probably need to use `CKEDITOR.replace('#Description',...`. With `#` sign to address the element by id.

Comment: No, there are no errors in the javascript console, and if I add the (#) sign, the editor doesn not load at all (without it it loads at least sometimes and empty)

Comment: As a sidenote, ASP.NET will reject anything that looks like HTML or JavaScript being posted to the server. Make sure you allow that property to pass its value to the server or your will get a lot of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need #. Do you use jquery? Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the description element to check it exists and that it has a value
    var d = $('#Description');
    alert(d.val(););

    // Create the editor
    CKEDITOR.replace('Description', {
        language: 'en'
    });
});
```

If you don't use jquery, try this:

```
function replaceCke(){
    // Get the description element to check it exists and that it has a value
    var d = document.getElementById("Description");
    alert(d.value);

    // Create the editor
    CKEDITOR.replace('Description', {
        language: 'en'
    });
}

if(window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', replaceCke, false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload', replaceCke);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me to understand the problem. I was calling the CKEDITOR.replace outside of the $(document).ready so the content wasn't (probably) loaded. Thank you :)